# Is my logistic regression model correct?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, computational-statistics

I have a factorial design 2*2 (A and B). Both variables with two responses high (coded as 1) and low (coded as 0) and I have a response variable $y$, my logistic model include interaction between A and B in R, I coded `logit<-glm(y~ A + B + A:B, data = df, family = "binomial")`.

I verified the data and everything is good. I even ensured the my variables are coded as factors, in the exercise I'm working on I demonstrated that (check the image) [image]

The $y$ in the picture are the average response.
The table used to calculate the coefficient is :
[image]

The coefficient I found using the formulas in the picture are not equal to the coefficient in the output of R (see image)
[image]

I don't understand where the problem is. I hope someone can explain to me the error I made.

Thank you.

Comment: Logistic regression is used when the outcome (Y) is binary. Is that the case for your data? I doesn't seem so. If Y is continuous, then logistic regression is the wrong tool. You may be confusing it with fitting a logistic model using nonlinear regression.

Comment: Y is not continuous it is a response taking 2 values 1 or 0

Comment: To clarify:  factor A, factor B, and Y all are binary with two levels?

Comment: yes they are : A takes high or low and the same for B its a 2*2 Design

Comment: This is just a possible explanation and I have not verified it.  If you coded A and B as factors than most likely R treated those values as a 1 and 2 and not your original 0 and 1.

Comment: @Dave2e when an N-level factor is put into the glm() formula argument, it is automatically separated into N-1 binary variables for the regression (one-hot encoded). So even if OP has them coded as factors, then there should be no difference between the binary encoding.

Comment: @MustaphaHakkouAsz this doesn't answer your question, but for future reference you can use y ~ A*B as your formula: it is shorthand for y ~ A + B + A:B

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating a function of exponentiated coefficients by plugging in probabilities from the model, R is reporting the index function coefficients that give you those probabilities. For example, the inverse logit of $-2.9444$ is $0.05$. You can use this to calculate the various $\bar y$s (or you can just calculate $y$ in each cell). The intercept corresponds to the low-low condition, so this matches the $\bar y_{LL}$ cell. I can reconstruct the exponentiated coefficients from ratios of the odds-ratios like this:

```
. scalar yll = invlogit(-2.9444)

. scalar yhl = invlogit(-2.9444 + 0.7472)

. scalar ylh = invlogit(-2.9444 + 1.2098)

. scalar yhh = invlogit(-2.9444 + 0.7472 + 1.2098 - 0.3989)

. 
. display "exp(alpha) = " exp(-2.9444)
exp(alpha) = .05263363

. display "exp(alpha) = " yll/(1-yll)
exp(alpha) = .05263363

. 
. display "exp(beta_1) = " exp(0.7472)
exp(beta_1) = 2.1110807

. display "exp(beta_1) = " ( yhl/(1-yhl) ) / ( yll/(1-yll) )
exp(beta_1) = 2.1110807

. 
. display "exp(beta_2) = " exp(1.2098)
exp(beta_2) = 3.352814

. display "exp(beta_2) = " ( ylh/(1-ylh) ) / ( yll/(1-yll) )
exp(beta_2) = 3.352814

. 
. display "exp(beta_12) = " exp(-0.3989)
exp(beta_12) = .6710578

. display "exp(beta_12) = " ((yhh/(1-yhh))/(yll/(1-yll)))/(( yhl/(1-yhl) ) / ( yll/(1-yll) )*( ylh/(1-ylh) ) / ( yll/(1-yll) ))
exp(beta_12) = .6710578
```

This is using the fact that since your model is

$$\ln \frac{p(d_1,d_2)}{1-p(d_1,d_2)} = \alpha + \beta_1 \cdot d_1 + \beta_2 \cdot d_2 + \beta_{12} \cdot d_{12},$$

when you take the exponent of both sides, you get
$$ \begin{align} \frac{p(d_1,d_2)}{1-p(d_1,d_2)} &= \exp( \alpha + \beta_1 \cdot d_1 + \beta_2 \cdot d_2 + \beta_{12} \cdot d_{12} ) \\ & =\exp(\alpha) \cdot \exp(\beta_1 \cdot d_1) \cdot \exp( \beta_2 \cdot d_2) \cdot \exp(\beta_{12} \cdot d_{12} ). \end{align}$$

For example,

$$ \begin{align} \frac{p(d_1=0,d_2=0)}{1-p(d_1=0,d_2=0)} &= \exp(\alpha), \end{align}$$

since $\exp(\beta \cdot 0) = 1.$ Here $p(d_1=0,d_2=0) = \bar y_{LL}.$

Then we move on to $\exp{\beta_1}$. From above, we know that

$$ \begin{align} \frac{p(d_1=1,d_2=0)}{1-p(d_1=1,d_2=0)} =\exp(\alpha) \cdot \exp(\beta_1).\end{align}$$

We already know what the first term on the right-hand side is from the previous step, and we can calculate the left-hand side, so we just need to divide through by $\exp(\alpha)$ to get $\exp(\beta_1)$.

Similarly, $$\exp(\beta_{12}) = \frac{ \frac{p(d_1=1,d_2=1)}{1-p(d_1=1,d_2=1)}}{\exp(\alpha) \cdot \exp(\beta_1) \cdot \exp( \beta_2))},$$

which is the odds ratio for $y_{HH}$ over the product of the other three odds ratios. You can definitely rearrange terms a bit here to simplify since all the $\frac{\bar y_{LL}}{1-\bar y_{LL}}$ terms should cancel out.

However, I don't know where the square roots or the twos in your formula are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients you see in the `glm()` output are those in the following formulation:

$\log(\frac{p}{1-p}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_1x_2$

These coefficients do not correspond to probabilities of class membership: they are partial derivatives of the log-odds (logit) of your response variable being 1 with respect to your regressors. You can rearrange the above to give:

$\hat{p} = \frac{\exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_1x_2)}{1 + \exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_1x_2)}$

To see that this works, let's plug in CYL1=1 and SS1=0. Don't forget the intercept.

$\hat{p} = \frac{\exp(-2.9 + 0.75*1 + 1.2*0 - .39*1*0)}{1 + \exp(-2.9 + 0.75*1 + 1.2*0 - .39*1*0)} = \frac{\exp(-2.9 + 0.75)}{1 + \exp(-2.9 + 0.75)} = 0.1$

This gives us the bottom-right value in your table. Doing this for all four possibilities should give you the values in the table.

If you want to use `predict()` to predict the probabilities of future data, supply the `type = "response"` argument in order to have the output in this probability form. Otherwise, you will be given predicted log odds values.